# setting the selected option of a select tag with jquery

Tags: php, jquery

If my jquery function is as below:

```
$('#shifts').change (function () 
    {

        $.get('ajax/time_menus.php', { shift: $('#shifts').val() },      
        function(data) 
        {
            $("#test").html( data );
         });
```

And returns a array with two time values contained in an array of six values:
[hours][minutes][ampm][hours][minutes][ampm]

How would I set the  values of 6 correlated  menus as to display the two times I just loaded.

Is there a way to set the  value via jquery or is it better to build the entire  menu's in php and then pass them back and set the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery, you can `select` different `<option>`s with the `val` function:

```
$('#my-select').val(yourValue);
```

Comment: But wont that set the value. I want to set the option of my choosing as <option selected>.

Comment: Or if you mean.. it would set #my-select where -select finds the slected #my then wouldn't i end up with possibly two <options with the same value.

Comment: I read your post as asking "how do I select an `option` of a `select` via jQuery".  If theres misunderstanding going on then you might edit your question to be clearer.

Comment: This does not select the item, it merely sets the value of the <select> element. This does not automatically select the appropriate option.

Comment: @idrumgood: wrong.  proof: <select id="test-select">
    <option value="val1">option1</option>
    <option value="val2">option2</option>
</select>
<script>
    $(function() {
        alert('changing');
        $('#test-select').val('val2');
    });
</script>

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#my-select option[value="yourValue"]').attr('selected','selected');
```