# How to use Ajax with select option tags in Jsp page ?

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets

In my jsp page , I have 2 different select option tags menü . I fill first one with a list from mysql database. when i select one value from this List ,I want to fill second select tag with a List which sended from Mysql . So , In Ajax , When i send a List from servlet to jsp , how to fill second Select option menu with this list in Jsp page ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [setting the selected option of a select tag with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363245/setting-the-selected-option-of-a-select-tag-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Use a javascript library like JQuery (that is well known and widely used/tested)

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/